# Receive email in IIS and insert into MYSQL

Tags: mysql, iis

I am using IIS to host a CMS I want to know is it possible either using the IIS or software to receive emails to the CMS and insert them into a MYSQL Database.

The email format in most instances is generated by a live system and the format stays the same with headers, to and from and body

It is basically like a live ticket system receiving mails adding it to MYSQL and then displaying it on the Dashboard

I have never tried this before and have no idea where to start. Numerous pages state using SMTP of IIS other state drawing the email using IMAP

Comment: IIS is a webserver and mysql is a database server. To send and receive emails you need a mail server. Sticking to the Microsoft product line, that's Exchange server. There are dozens of other mail servers out there - some free, some commercial.

Comment: The SMTP module on IIS is used to send email, not receive email. So you need a SMTP server and it only exist in IIS6. SMTP server also need to install on windows server. Please refer to [this](https://www.py4u.net/discuss/1185675) about configure SMTP on server.